# Question about class in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

If I have this code:

```
 <div id="one">
        <label>first</label> 
        <select name="area" class="area">
        <option selected="selected">First</option>
    </div>

 <div id="two">
        <label>second</label> 
        <select name="area" class="area">
        <option selected="selected">Second</option>
 </div>
```

Is it possible something like this?

```
  $("#one: .area").change(function() {}

or 

 $("#two: .area").change(function() {}
```

It doesn't work, could someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you want

```
$("#one > select.area").change(function() {});
```

or

```
$("#two > select.area").change(function() {}
```

Also Make sure you end your select tag. You have the following HTML

```
<div id="one">
    <label>first</label> 
    <select name="area" class="area">
    <option selected="selected">First</option>
</div>
```

It should be

```
<div id="one">
    <label>first</label> 
    <select name="area" class="area">
        <option selected="selected">First</option>
    </select>  <!-- Note the Ending tag for the select -->
</div>
```

Comment: Only valid if you can guarantee it is a direct child.

Comment: +1, particularly for using `select.area` rather than just `.area`.

Comment: @josh.trow: I think that's a safe assumption given the code sample in the question.

Comment: @Town: True, but I don't want Fel coming back and complaining it isn't working when he puts it inside another styled `div` or something.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<div id="one">
        <label>first</label> 
        <select name="area" class="area">
        <option selected="selected">First</option>
         </select>
    </div>

 <div id="two">
        <label>second</label> 
        <select name="area" class="area">
        <option selected="selected">Second</option>
        </select>
 </div>

$("#one select.area").change(function() {}
```

Comment: Good precision - I often see selectors that are too vague and thereby get too many objects.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `:` in your code...
`$("#one .area")` 
Also would be good practice to close your select elements `</select>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you should remove the `:` in the selector.

```
$("#one .area").change(function() { alert($(this).val()) });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra unnecessary `:` in your selector, use: `$("#one .area").change(function() {});`

See this for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fermin/9YM3a/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to select the `.area` that is the child of `#one` or `#two` then you almost have it right.

`$('#one > .area').change(function() {}`

The `>` means "The child of" so you will be selecting the `.area` that is the child of `#one`

Comment: Leaving out the `>` is less specific but means the selctor will still work if a div like `<div class="one_inner">` is added around the `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div as the scope.

```
$('.area',$(this).parent('div:one')).change(function() {}
```